# Find DivTag element in list and click when innerHTML matches account name

Tags: c#, webdriver

I need to click on a "**account**" button from a table of buttons. If this "**account**" button is not present, then I will need to click a different "**UseAnotherAccount**"
 button.

How I do it at the moment is:

- Set a flag `account_found` to be false by default
- use a `foreach` loop to search through the whole `_list` of buttons
- If the expected account button is found, click it, set `account_found` flag to be true and break away from this `foreach` loop
- an additional `if` block is used to to click on `UseAnotherAccount` button if `account_found` flag is not set.

My code is shown below:

```
bool account_found = false;
foreach (DivTag element in _list) {
    String account_name = element.GetInnerHtml();
    if (account_name.Equals(_account_name)) {
        element.Click();
        account_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!account_found) {
    _my_repo.SignInToYourAccount.UseAnotherAccount.Click();
}
```

I have this feeling my way is not the most elegant way to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume that this question involves code for [tag:selenium]?

Comment: @200_success, not really, it was developed for Ranorex platform. But in principle, we could interpret the code as if it was written in Selenium, basically same purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate the need for the flag you could do it like this:

```
var element = _my_repo.SignInToYourAccount.UseAnotherAccount;
foreach (var item in _list)
{
    if (item.GetInnerHtml().Equals(_account_name))
    {
        element = item;
        break;
    }
}
element.Click();
```

However, your code can be greatly simplified with the Linq extension methods provided in the `System.Linq`namespace:

```
var element = _list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetInnerHtml().Equals(_account_name)) ?? _my_repo.SignInToYourAccount.UseAnotherAccount;
element.Click();
```